# adding options to a <select> element with innerHTML+= works?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to display the courses from the chosen term using js, it seems that I should be able to add option with innerHTML+= or with creation a option element and adding it to the selection element, neither methods work. (I checked that the courses array is working perfectly and the function gets called)

PHP:

```
class Course{
            public $name;
            public $id;
            public $term;
            public $credits;

            function __construct($name,$id,$term,$credits){
                $this -> name = $name;
                $this -> id = $id;
                $this -> term = $term;
                $this -> credits = $credits;
            }
            function getName() {
                return $this->name;
            }
            function getId() {
                return $this->id;
            }
            function getTerm() {
                return $this->term;
            }
            function getCredits() {
                return $this->credits;
            }
        }
        
        try {
            // Establish the database connection
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbName", $username, $password);
            
            // Set the PDO error mode to exception
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            
            // Prepare and execute the query
            $query = "SELECT * FROM course";
            $statement = $db->query($query);
            //var_dump($statement);
            
            // Fetch the results as an associative array
            $results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            //var_dump($results);

            // Process the results
            foreach ($results as $row) {
                $courseName = $row['courseName'];
                $courseId = $row['courseId'];
                $courseCredits = $row['courseCredits'];
                $courseTerm = $row['courseTerm'];

                
                $course = new Course($courseName,$courseId,$courseTerm,$courseCredits);
                array_push($courses,$course);
                
                // Do something with the retrieved data
                //echo "Course: $courseName | Id: $courseId | Credits: $courseCredits | Term: $courseTerm <br>";
            }
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            // Display an error message in case of connection failure
            echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

        //var_dump($courses);
        $jsonArray = json_encode($courses);
```

js:

```
let courses = [];
        class Course {
            constructor(name, id, credits, term) {
                this.name = name;
                this.id = id;
                this.credits = credits;
                this.term = term;
            }
        }
courses = <?php echo $jsonArray; ?>;

function displayClasses(){
    console.log("displayClasses()");
    let term = document.getElementById("term").value;
    let output = document.getElementById("className");

    output.innerHTML="";
    console.log(courses[2].term);
    for (let i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
        if (courses[i].term == term) {
            //method 1//
            output.innerHTML+=("<option value='"+courses[i].name+"'>"+courses[i].name+"</option>");
            
            /* method 2
            var opt = document.createElement('OPTION');
            opt.text = courses[i].name;
            opt.value = courses[i].name;
            output.options.add(opt);
            */
        }
    }
}
```

html:

```
            <div>
                <label for="term">Term</label>
                <select id="term" onchange="displayClasses();">
                    <option value="term1">1</option>
                    <option value="term2">2</option>
                    <option value="term3">3</option>
                    <option value="term4">4</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="className">Class Name</label>
                <select id="className">
                </select>
            </div>
```

Comment: You use the `courses` variable in your code, but your code doesn't show where `courses` is defined. Also, for the second method, you would use `output.add(opt)` not `output.options.add(opt)`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add) for reference.

Comment: courses is an array that seems to be working. console.log(courses[i].term) prints exactly as expected

Comment: It would still help us to know, where it is defined, because we won't be able to reproduce it without that information. Is it a global variable? When is it set?

Comment: Ditto. So that we can rule out any problems with the other variables, please show more of the code or consider writing in an example value.

Comment: I added the rest of the code showing where courses array comes from

Comment: The _term_ values in the courses array need to match the option values exactly, e.g. "term1", "term2".

Comment: @Hodgson that was it, can you post it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works, depending on the *courses* array, as Geshode suggested.

```js
courses = [
  { term: "term1", name: "English" },
  { term: "term1", name: "Spanish" },
  { term: "term1", name: "Mandarin" },
  { term: "term2", name: "Physics" },
  { term: "term2", name: "Biology" },
  { term: "term2", name: "Chemistry" },
];

function displayClasses() {
  let term = document.getElementById("term").value;
  let output = document.getElementById("className");

  output.innerHTML = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
    console.log(term, courses[i].term);
    if (courses[i].term == term) {
      output.innerHTML +=
        "<option value='" +
        courses[i].name +
        "'>" +
        courses[i].name +
        "</option>";

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="term">Term</label>
  <select id="term" onchange="displayClasses();">
<option value="term1">1</option>
<option value="term2">2</option>
<option value="term3">3</option>
<option value="term4">4</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="className">Class Name</label>
  <select id="className">
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a very problematic way to build up the HTML.  You open yourself to attacks and broken applications because you are injecting text content directly into the HTML context.  You should set `textContent` and property and attribute values instead of what you're doing here.